# How to throw an exception upon first invocation and a regular return value on the second?

Tags: unit-testing, dart, mocking, mockito

My code makes network calls. Sometimes these fail and I've implemented some [retry](https://pub.dev/packages/retry) logic. Now I wish to test this with a unit test. I'm using [Mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) for this. I'm having trouble mocking this particular method call, this is my test code:

```
var mock = MockHttpClient();
var answers = <Future<String>>[
  Future.error(Exception('boom')),
  Future.value('some return value'),
];
when(mock.getStuff()).thenAnswer((_) => answers.removeAt(0));

var client = Client(inner: mock);

var result = client.someCall(); // This method call uses the `inner` object to make the `getStuff` network call.
expect(result, 'some return value');
```

Running this code throws an exception. And I get that because of the first returned `Future`! Mockito has the appropriate method call named [`thenThrow`](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/PostExpectation/thenThrow.html) but I can't figure out how to combine the two.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. The trick is not to use a [`Mock`](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/Mock-class.html) but a [`Fake`](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/Fake-class.html).
That looks like this:

```
class FakeHttpClient extends Fake implements HttpClient {
  final List<Future<List<String>>> answers = [
    Future.error(Exception('boom')),
    Future.value('some return value'),
  ];

  @override
  Future<String> getStuff() {
    return answers.removeAt(0);
  }
}
```

Then use an instance of `FakeHttpClient` as an argument to the original example's `Client`:

```
var fake = FakeHttpClient();
var client = Client(inner: fake);

var result = client.someCall(); // This method call uses the `inner` object to make the `getStuff` network call.
expect(result, 'some return value');
```